# CakePHP cannot find UsersController

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been following the blog tutorial on cakephp.org and I had adding and editing the posts table working fine. I wanted to add a user login but I am having trouble when following the tutorial. When I run my application now I keep getting the error:

Error: UsersController could not be found.

Error: Create the class UsersController below in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php

I know the controller is definitely there, I followed naming conventions, and I can't find any errors in the code for UsersController.php or anything else. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

EDIT: clearing caches don't seem to be the problem. All that is there is an empty text file.

Thanks, 
   Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check file permissions, it should be readable by everyone.

Clear your cache in /app/tmp/cache/models, /app/tmp/cache/persistent

Comment: /app/tmp/cache/models and /app/tmp/cache/persistent both seemed to just have empty text files. I'm trying to launch this through Heroku; I don't know if that changes anything. It was finding my controllers before I added user authentication however.

Comment: If the problem came out after you have added Auth the problem should be around that. So I would recommend you to comment out all the auth code, check if your app work like that. If yes than double check your added auth code.

Comment: I rolled back a few steps in the tutorial and then did it all over again and it worked. No idea exactly where the problem was but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

you have problem in your cache 
delete all rep in your /app/tmp/cache/models

Answer (score 1):

If you copy those examples from a tutorials page, make sure you copy the php tags at the beginning of your file

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your debug mode is ON .

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Go in config/core.php file

Answer (score 0):

ensure there is no white space between the start of the page and the php opening tags

Comment: Hi Joseph and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure you have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before posting answers. Adding some code to your answer and making it more explanative may help other users take the greatest benefit from it!